# http timeout errors in some locations

Tags: php, http, networking, timeout

our domain is showing HTTP TIMEOUT after 30+ seconds in some of the locations, viz., LONDON, Auckland, Berlin, Brussels. In rest of the areas, it is working fine and loading within 3 seconds.

**what specific ways of finding the reason behind it and how to fix it**

Comment: Doing a `traceroute` from different locations and seeing if there are any bottlenecks.

Comment: maybe the site is blocked by the gov isp..pls check is there is any blocking

Answer (score 0):

[Try checking your network connections to the server using Pingdom, most likily a server/network problem rather than php. https://tools.pingdom.com/](https://tools.pingdom.com/)